# making output from numpy array with double brackets

Tags: python, numpy

I am new in python, and I want to make an output from each array inside brackets:

input array:

```
d=[[1,20]],[[2,20],[3,20]],[[4,20]]]
```

output is like:

```
[[1,20]]

[[2,20]]

[[3,20]]

[[4,20]]
```

but I am looking for an output like:

```
[[1,20]]

[[2,20], [3,20]]

[[4,20]]
```

can someone help me to find how to solve this problem!?

```
for i in range (len(d)):
      for j in range(len(d[i])):
            c = [d[i][j]]
            print c
```

Comment: Is it just for those values or will this be extended to bigger arrays? If it will be extended what is the pattern you are looking for in the output?  Every second and third are on the same line??

Comment: it can extend for sure, and patter is completely random

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I misread the input array.  Disregard my previous comment.

Comment: for example: [[1,20]],[[2,20],[3,20]],[[4,20]],[[5,20]], [[6,20],[7,20]]]

Comment: this is the code, that I am using:

Comment: for i in range (len(d)):
      for j in range(len(d[i])):
            c = [d[i][j]]
            print c

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
for i in d:
  print(i)
```

Your code was just going a layer too deep.